# How to fetch user credentials of a windows service using powershell or python

Tags: python, powershell

I was doing a project in my organization where I need to either fetch the credentials which are used to run a specific service or use the similar credentials while deleting and recreating the same service.

Issue description: In my organization whenever we change/add new features we need to upgrade the older agent installed in one windows machine. To do a correct upgrades we first uninstall the older build and install the latest version. While uninstalling we loose the older credentials which were used to run a service and new installed service doesn't runs as expected. I was looking for a mechanism where I can automatically save/persist the older credentials while installing the new agent version. 
Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Probably a service account is being used to run a service. There is no way that I know of where you can get the password information of another account. OS pretty much locks down any such attempts. Best you can do is get the account name and use that to reconfigure ur newly installed service to use that account. But you have to know the password.

Comment: You can get the Username of a service with WMIC e.g. `wmic service spooler get startname` the password however you cannot, this is Hashed.

Comment: Thanks for the info Sid and Panomosh. Does windows stores password information of a service in registry?